# How to move tiles body to left or right in andengine

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

I need help to move a body (not sprite) along the x axis in Left or Right direction, using on screen controller.
I have a player in my gamescene class which is located at the center of the screen, and two left & right controller buttons.
My expectations are that the body should move along X axis to certain points say -100 or -200 points when gamer clicks on left or right controller button player.
I am using the code below to move body which is not working

```
public void turnLeft() 
{
body.setTransform(body.getPosition().x-100, body.getPosition().y)
}
```

Can anybody help me on this please?

Regards,
Deepak

Comment: Try using setLinearVelocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use setTransform() you should use it with a vector2 object. Your example would be:

```
private float p2m = PhysicsConstants.PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO_DEFAULT;

public void turnLeft() {
    body.setTransform(new Vector2((body.getPosition().x-100)/p2m, body.getPosition().y/p2m), 0);
}
```

You need to divide by p2m = 32 because box2d does not operates in pixels but in meters (read about it here: [AndEngine: Use of PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991622/andengine-use-of-pixel-to-meter-ratio)).

Comment: No problem. Keep creating!